# How far can you go in SkyBlock with limited starting gear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

What would be the minimum number of items needed to get as far as possible in *Minecraft* SkyBlock?

I'm thinking sapling grass block and dirt block and maybe an emerald. This can lead to a fair amount of items without hoping for a random chance of a biome or wandering trader to spawn.

Comment: How do you define "far"? Physical distance? Then a dirt block and a sapling would be enough. If you mean beating the dragon, then it depends what you do with the End dimension, since it's not affected by custom world generation. Anyway, I think you might be interested in my "SkyChest" challenge: https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/skychest-4322464/

Comment: Assuming that you have something to stand on, a spawn egg for a villager with a custom trade would also be sufficient for infinite travel. There are some near-misses with less fancy items, my favourite is the water bucket: Drowned can spawn in water, you can punch them to death and obtain copper ingots… but you can never craft them into blocks, because you don't have a crafting table. There are many ways to get one, none work in that situation.

Comment: You don't actually need the emerald, as foxes spawn with them.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward start would be **1 block and 1 sapling**.

- In the Overworld, this would be a dirt block and a sapling.
- In the Nether, it would be a nylium block, a fungus, and a bonemeal.

**Sapling growth and Nether start:**
While in the Overworld time would be enough to grow the sapling, the fungus would require bonemeal. I still recommend starting in the Nether, even with the extra item, as it allows you to have access to 2 dimensions without granting the player lava. (gather gold, barter for obsidian + fire charge, gain access to the Overworld)

**Passive mobs:**
Well, you won't be getting many of these. With no grass, you can't access passive mobs. (The wandering trader can help you out a little here, proving you with a dirt alternative that can be multiplied. Mycelium could be obtained by growing a giant mushroom on the dirt, which can spawn Mooshrooms in specific biomes, foxes spawn on snow, and frogs spawn on mud blocks in swamps, I believe).

I'd recommend having at least 1 grass block in the world to have access to more content. Preferably somewhere where it won't spawn passive mobs that will eat the grass before you get close to it.

**Water:**
Obtaining water won't be a problem. Kill zombies for *iron*, make cauldrons and a bucket, and wait for rain (in a non-dry biome).

**Cobblestone:**
Nope. Without lava, you can't get access to these goodies. With access to the Nether, blackstone can be used to craft furnaces and such, but *Redstone components* aren't part of those crafting recipes. (The most annoying part: having to rely on boat clocks... )

**Villagers:**
Villagers are obtainable as long as you have a source of gold and apples. Gold can be obtained from a Nether start or lightning-converted pigs (pigs would require grass, and dirt to farm crops). A witch can replace the weakness potion.

**The Nether:**
Either start in the Nether or have some non-vanilla way to get lava. (Giving the player lava is possible, but you will need the wandering trader for *dripstone* to multiply it).

**The End:**
Okay, you will have to have end portals generated if you plan on getting to the end. No way around this. You will need access to the nether too, for the Blaze Rods/Eyes of Ender.

All in all, you can get quite a few blocks, and build amazing things but the bottlenecks are going to be lava & grass (& apples). You won't get villagers in an Overworld start without a way to get grass or lava. Not getting to certain biomes, and no wandering traders doesn't help.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I knew nether start was possible but I never thought about it honestly what a great idea

Comment: @Vokuar The main problems with a nether start are that fungus growth with bonemeal is random and that you can lose your nylium. You will have to sneak and try to grow the fungus, and then quickly break the bottom wood block before the nylium ticks to netherrack.  Make a composter and compost the fungus leaves, and then try to get another fungus by bonemealing the nylium. Surround the nylium with some blocks for a better chance at a fungus. Rays Works has a nice series ([ProtoSky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WgsD3qBtlo&list=PL-5egZTw99_6bTucOUg7sj0RY8aUvVwFO)) about a start as described.

Comment: how would one respawn in the nether cuz dying once respawns you back in overworld so far ive been using /execute in minecraft:the_nether run tp 0 64 0 (which is where my patch of nether land is) but how would i make this automatic i assume command blocks detecting death in the nether perhaps

Comment: A full respawn anchor could work if you can stand taking the extra block. My strategy was 'not dying' and the TP if I did. If you want to use a command block, maybe a repeating command to replace the respawn anchor with a full one? it would prevent the player from repeatedly dying/destroying it to go to the overworld.